# Java: How to group entities by condition using Stream API?

Tags: java, group-by, streaming, java-stream

I have a list of users.

```
class User {
    String name;
}
```

And I need to group users by name.

```
List<Set<User>> groupedBy;
```

The grouping condition is the name similarity, it's some Comparator

```
Comparator<User> p = new Comparator<User>() {
    // some comparison logic
};
```

How can I group users by similar name using Java 8 streams?

I've tried to use `partitioning`, but it has a different API than I need.

```
Map<Boolean, List<User>> collected = users.stream().collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(new Predicate<User>() {
    @Override
    public boolean test(User user) {
        // ...
    }
}, Collectors.toList()));
```

Comment: you're trying to `group` based on a Predicate? that sounds like `partitioning`.

Comment: Sorry, based on name comparator.

Comment: How would you do it without stream api? Thinking of something like levenstein distance, it will not result in a clearly separated set as it is not transitive.

Answer (score 4):

Normally, if you want to group via a simple property, you’d use

```
Map<String,Set<User>> m=users.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(User::getName, Collectors.toSet()));
```

however, if you have a complicated logic that is expressed as an already existing `Comparator`, e.g.

```
Comparator<User> comparator=Comparator.comparing(u -> u.getName(), Collator.getInstance());
```

you can use

```
Map<User,Set<User>> m=users.stream().collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(u -> u, () -> new TreeMap<>(comparator), Collectors.toSet()));
```

to group according to the logic encapsulated in the comparator.

In both cases, you get a `Map` which can be converted to your desired list using

```
List<Set<User>> groupedBy = new ArrayList<>(m.values());
```

You can also express the last step as part of the `Collector`, e.g.

```
List<Set<User>> groupedBy=users.stream().collect(
    Collectors.collectingAndThen(
        Collectors.groupingBy(u -> u, () -> new TreeMap<>(comparator), Collectors.toSet()),
        m -> new ArrayList<Set<User>>(m.values())));
```

Comment: yes... why not just supply the comparator to a Map that accepts one? one plus